# VBA How to check if a worksheet name is number

Tags: excel, vba

I have entered the following code in my VBA sub:

```
Sub copy2sheet()
Dim wkSht As Worksheet    
    For Each wkSht In Sheets
        If IsNumeric(wkShrt.Name) Then
            Worksheets("Anleitung").Range("A1") = "a"
        Else
            Worksheets("Anleitung").Range("B1") = "a"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I need to proceed in the following process only with those sheets, which have a numeric name (they are all of the form "yymmdd").
However, executing it gives me a 424 runtime error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and this will identify all such typos, before run-time.  It will save you many hours of trouble, in the future :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo on line 4 which gives the `Error 424 Object Required`:

```
If IsNumeric(wkShrt.Name) Then
```

Should be

```
If IsNumeric(wkSht.Name) Then
```

Comment: Thanks. And that cost me about an hour...
David: I had used Option Explicit - how can this help me identifying typos?

Comment: @MichaelteHeesen Happy to help. If my answer solver your problem please accept it.